# Estimate nonlinear Regression Parameter With Recursive Formula

Tags: r, statistics, regression, non-linear-regression

I have a nonlinear regression such as below:

y_t= (theta)*sum(((1-theta)^k)*(x_(t-k))) + alpha * (gamma-z_t)

that x_t and z_t are independent variables, theta and alpha and gamma are parameters.
To estimate the parameters, I wrote this recursive function:

```
w_t<-function(theta,x,t){
s<-0
for (i in 0:(t-1)){
s<- s + theta * (x[t-i])*((1-theta)^i)
}
return(s)
}
```

that calculate the first sentence of the regression model with knowing the theta value. How can I estimate the theta and other parameters in this model?